# Log shipping large database

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, vldb

I have Question on log shipping:

I am migrating a VLDB (12TB) SQL database from a physical environment (server A) to virtual environment (server B), and from version SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2014.

The high-level plan for migration is to log ship from server A to server B during a transition\test period. Once we’re happy with testing we simply make server B the new production environment. During this period server B needs to receive periodic log restores (once or twice per day) and be in read-only\standby mode for testing.

I have the added complexity of A and B existing in related but different domains, and I also want to use the existing `.trn` files that are currently being created via the existing Ola Hallengren regime. So basically, I just want to utilize the COPY & RESTORE aspects of log shipping on server B by picking up trn’s from a network share.

Before I attempt this with the VLDB I am testing the concept on a much smaller DB.

The issues I’m getting are :

- When I try to get server B into standby mode I get this error:

> This backup cannot be restored using WITH STANDBY because a database upgrade is needed. Reissue the RESTORE without WITH STANDBY

Stack overflow Questions [3010115](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010115/how-do-we-setup-a-remote-standby-read-only-database-to-accept-log-shipping) and [40760521](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760521/this-backup-cannot-be-restored-using-with-standby-because-a-database-upgrade-is) are similar but unfortunately provide no solution.

Any help or other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since you are crossing database versions, it might be difficult using this approach.  I would suggest looking at a product called Double Take.  Check it out https://www.visionsolutions.com

Comment: Just to confirm that log shipping is a dead end. As the error suggests, standby does the whole recovery process and the recovery process involves (requires) upgrading the database. And it not possible if you then want to restore further backups since that would require a downgrade which has never been an option. I.e., an impossible situation - hence the error.